# Is there a way to make check on HEX color - Cypress

Tags: javascript, testing, cypress

I am currently busy with testing on Cypress . I am actually new so i am not so familiar with everything around , but i am trying to test a CSS property of `background-color` on certain element , but the problem is that behind the scenes everything is RGB , but i need to test on HEX . So i ask myself is there a way to do that or a translation should be necessary ?

```
  cy.get('#button-login')
   .should('have.css', 'background-color', "#6a7ba3")
```

****ERROR** :** `...to have CSS property 'background-color' with the value '#6a7ba3', but the value was 'rgb(106, 123, 163)'`

Comment: Is the question how to turn hex codes to rgb?

Comment: Did you read e.g. https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/2186?

Comment: Another possibility is to install the chai-colors assertion library, then you can do something like  `cy.get('#button-login').should('have.css', 'background-color').and('be.colored', '#6a7ba3')`

Comment: @JohnM how does this library is used inside of the Cypress . I cannot understand clear enough . Thanks

Comment: See [https://www.chaijs.com/plugins/chai-colors/](https://www.chaijs.com/plugins/chai-colors/)

Comment: @JohnM i found my way out . If you want you can make it as an proper answer to help others and i will accept it . Thanks mate

Comment: Good to hear. I've added it as an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can achieve what you want using the [chai-colors](https://www.chaijs.com/plugins/chai-colors/) assertion plugin.

Install as follows:

```
npm install chai-colors
```

Then add this to your code:

```
import chaiColors from 'chai-colors'
chai.use(chaiColors)
```

Or this, as applicable:

```
var chaiColors = require('chai-colors');    
chai.use(chaiColors);
```

Now you can write your assertion like this:

```
cy.get('#button-login')
  .should('have.css', 'background-color')
  .and('be.colored', '#6a7ba3')
```

Comment: I am getting error The chainer colored was not found. Could not build assertion.

Comment: Suggest you post a new question including a full code sample

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73445559/cypress-error-the-chainer-colored-was-not-found-could-not-build-assertion

Comment: Does it has types? [ typescript]

Answer (score 0):

I was facing error with `chai-colors` so I used the `tinycolor2` library to assert the color as follows

```
import Toast from './index';

import { themedMount } from '../../../cypress/index';
import tinycolor from 'tinycolor2';

const toastColorMap: Record<string, string> = {
  success: '#cff5c4',
  error: '#fbcfc8',
};
const toasts = [
  { _id: '1', message: 'success toast notification', type: 'success' },
  { _id: '2', message: '2 success toast notification', type: 'error' },
  { _id: '3', message: 'error toast notification', type: 'error' },
];
describe('Toast.cy.tsx', () => {
  it('Toast component renders toasts properly', () => {
    themedMount(<Toast toasts={toasts} />);
    toasts.forEach((t) => {
      const toastElement = cy.contains(t.message);
      toastElement.should('have.css', 'background-color').then((bg) => {
        const color = tinycolor(bg);
        expect(color.toHexString()).equal(toastColorMap[t.type]);
      });
    });
  });
});
```