# Cypress error The chainer colored was not found. Could not build assertion

Tags: cypress, chai, assertion

Below is my code, when I use this cypress test, I am getting the error
**Cypress error The chainer colored was not found. Could not build assertion.**

```
import chai from 'chai';
import chaiColors from 'chai-colors';
chai.use(chaiColors);

const toasts = [
  { _id: '1', message: 'success toast notification', type: 'success' },
  { _id: '2', message: '2 success toast notification', type: 'error' },
  { _id: '3', message: 'error toast notification', type: 'error' },
];
describe('Toast.cy.tsx', () => {
  it('Toast component renders toasts properly', () => {
    themedMount(<Toast toasts={toasts} />);
    toasts.forEach((t) => {
      const toastElement = cy.contains(t.message);
      toastElement
        .should('have.css', 'background-color')
        .and('be.colored', '#fbcfc8');
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Cypress modifies `chai` to use it in the `.should()` and `.and()` commands.

If you import chai and apply chaiColors to that instance, it will not be available in the Cypress commands.

Remove `import chai from 'chai'` and it should work.

```js
import chaiColors from 'chai-colors';
chai.use(chaiColors);                   // apply plugin to the global chai
```

---

#### Use onecolor instead

Please also see my note here [Test color with chai-colors plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73029890/16997707) about flaky color assertions due to `rgb` and `rgba` differences.

Importing and directly using the `onecolor` library is a better idea because  it has conversion methods you can apply.

Comment: I see, the problem, happened because I thought I should import chai, before using it, but as soon as I wrote the import statement, it prompted me with error, chai not found and when I manually installed chai, it gave the error that I wrote above!